Why does ODR not apply to `dll` when dynamically link it in a program?
Consider this example:
// the common header file:
// common.h
class A {
public:
    static void fun() {

    }
};


the side of dll file
// test.h
#pragma once
extern "C" {
    _declspec(dllexport) void print_addr();
}

// test.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "common.h"
#include "head.h"
void print_addr() {
    auto r = &A::fun;
    std::cout << "dll " << (void*)r << std::endl;
}

The main program side:
#include "common.h"
#include <iostream>
extern "C" void print_addr();
int main() {
    print_addr();
    auto r = &A::fun;
    std::cout << "main " << (void*)r << std::endl;
}

The outcome is
dll 00007FF82EC713B6
main 00007FF7AD77143D

The addresses of A::fun in the program and dll are different. However, according to [class.mfct] p1

If a member function is attached to the global module and is defined ([dcl.fct.def]) in its class definition, it is inline ([dcl.inline]).

A::fun is an inline function, and its definition does not violate [basic.def.odr] p15

For any definable item D with definitions in multiple translation units,


if D is a non-inline non-templated function or variable, or
[...]


For each such entity and for D itself, the behavior is as if there is a single entity with a single definition, including in the application of these requirements to other entities.

So, A::funs in dll and the program that dynamically links it should refer to the same entity.
Why does the outcome indicate they are distinct entities?

Dlls are not covered by the standard.

In addition to Raymond Chen's answer, this is specific to Windows DLLs. If you compile this on Linux (with slight adjustments because Linux doesn't have declspec(dllexport)), the address will be the same by default, but if you hide non-explicitly exported symbols (which more closely resembles the behavior of Windows), they won't be. So just a single compiler option while generating the library on Linux can change this behavior.

If your comipiler isn't doing what the standard requires that's a flaw in your compiler. DLLs don't get an exemption from the rules.

Clearly there are different rules for DLLs, since each DLL has its own DllMain function which would be an ODR violation if they were all considered one program.

Since, so far, there are no black helicopters that arrive to enforce conformance with the C++ standard, there will always be cases in which implementors choose behavior that does not conform to your view of the standard. Microsoft, and Linux with certain options, sees shared libraries as independent units for ODR purposes.
